# How to filter in rdd containing array of tuples?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data like this Array of Array of tuple(Int,Int,String).

```
val data = Array(Array((1,200,"vimal"),(2,12,"amar"),(1,120,"vimal"),  
   (2,120,"kamal"),(1,120,"jay")),Array((1,200,"vimal"),(1,120,"vimal"),
   (2,120,"kamal"),(1,120,"jay")))
val dist = sc.parallelize(data)
```

I would like to filter the tuples containing 2 as the first integer.

The result should look like

```
(2,12,"amar"),(2,120,"kamal"),(2,120,"kamal")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
dist.flatMap { arrayElement =>
  arrayElement filter {
    case (x: Int, y: Int, str: String) => x == 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!! This made me understand the difference between map and flatmap. The distinct is not needed though . I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Using a for comprehension like this,

```
for ( xs <- data; t @ (a,b,c) <- xs if a == 2 ) yield t
```

where `t` is bound to each tuple and we filter those tuples where there first item is 2. Likewise

```
for ( t @ (a,b,c) <- data.flatten if a == 2 ) yield t
```

conveys the result; here we flatten out the nested arrays first. Even shorter is this,

```
for ( t <- data.flatten if t._1 == 2 ) yield t
```

And as short as it gets (using `filter` as already proposed),

```
data.flatten.filter(_._1 == 2)
```

With `collect`, consider this pattern matching,

```
data.flatten.collect { case t @ (2,_,_) => t }
```

Also we can partition a flattened version of `data` by the desired `criteria` (first item in tuple is 2), and get the first element from the partitioning tuple,

```
data.flatten.partition(_._1 == 2)._1
```